# Javascript MVC - separate logic

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I currently use my own setup for an MVC framework in Javascript, but I am a bit confused about the fact, on where I should put my HTML events handlers.

Like click/mouse/focus event and stuff like that, is it acceptable to attach this event-logic into the controller.

Right now, I have it like this:

- Some-module.model.js
- Some-module.view.js (where I attach my user-events, like mouse events, focus etc)
- Some-module.view.tpl (this is where the HTML is being placed between script-tags, mini-templating engine)
- Some-module.controller.js

So, is it wisely to attach the click handlers for the view into the controller? or is that bad practise?

Comment: I think that is exactly what a view controller class is for, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Putting event handlers inside of a controller class is not bad practice.  In fact, the **JavaScriptMVC** library uses a Controller class to organize all event handlers (although this is not the sole purpose of the Controller class).

Putting event handlers inside of a View class is not bad practice either, as this is used by **Backbone.js** to organize all event handlers associated with a particular DOM element.

There are plenty of front-end MVC design patterns, and there is not one boilerplate that will fit perfectly for every situation.

Answer (score 0):

Save the javascript and all the DOM manipulation in a `js` file.

*[Separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)*

BTW: `Controller` is sort of `keyword` in MVC, you might want to change th js file name, to a name without controller inside of it.

Comment: But the controller is a JS file ... And how is controlling the interaction with its view not of concern to the controller?

Comment: Well I am keeping the 'controller' in the file name, it is pleasant to see what kind of file I am editing while developing. When the site is being deployed, all JS files will be merged automatically.

But what do you mean with 'save all DOM manipulations in a JS file' ?

Comment: @barry. Like `$('.foo').addClass('bar').val('a value');` or `$('#foo').change();` or `$('#foo').hide();` etc'

Comment: @gdoron: So DOM manipulations go inside the view part right?
And attaching click-events, also inside the view?

In that case I have two views, one template and one for attaching user-events and DOM manipulations?

Comment: @barry. One or two files isn't important. I recommend put it in a `js` file in the view. Not directly in the view.

Answer (score 0):

Okay thanks all!

What I am going todo:

/controllers/
 -> some-module.js

/models/
 -> some-module.js
(holds data, keep track of states, retreive data)

/views/
 -> some-module.js
(attaching DOM events, DOM manipulations, will retreive the template TPL file and use it)

/templates/
 -> some-module.tpl
(the actual view in script-tags, similar to mustache or Jquery Templates, allows me to use variable-tags in the template)

This will keep my application organized and modular.

I could consider handling DOM events inside the controller, but I also need a location to execute some DOM manipulations (changing classnames, changing innerHTML values etc.), and I think that the controller is not the correct way to do that.